# How to properly use useQuery remove?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Consider the following simple example in which I fetch data from a URL every two seconds:

```js
    const fetchData = async () => {
        console.info('fetching');
        const result = (await api.get(`/`)).data;
        return result.data;
    };

    useQuery(['mykey'], fetchData, {
        refetchInterval: 2000,
    });
```

This all works as expected. Every two seconds `fetching` is printed to the console.

However suppose I don't want to continue fetching this anymore. My thought was to use `useQuery.remove()` for that. The documentation on `remove` says the following:

`A function to remove the query from the cache.`

Perfect. So I modified the example above to the following:

```js
    const { remove } = useQuery(['mykey'], fetchData, {
        refetchInterval: 2000,
    });

    // ... do stuff and then remove the periodic fetch:
    remove();
```

However upon calling that `remove()`, suddenly `fetchData()` is called continuously and the console is flooded with the `fetching` message.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are clearing the cache so it's not in the cache after the operation so query have to run again. You don't want to clear the cache. If you want to stop the interval either use `enabled` option or set `refetchInteraval` to `false`

Comment: Thanks! Alhthough, This is a bit counter intuitive to me, I just want to get rid of the entry I added using `useQuery`. Setting `enabled` to `false` or changing the `refetchInterval`, feels like a workaround or a hack to me. Isn't there a proper way to just undo the action I caused by calling `useQuery`?

Comment: Removing the query from the cache means removing data. It doesn't stop the query from fetching again due to having no data in the cache.